# Ship JDBC driver into WAR for Tomcat 7

Tags: jdbc, jndi, tomcat7

Before updating to Tomcat 7 (from Tomcat 6) I was able to ship MySql JDBC driver with a WAR file. I wasn't experiencing any issues creating JNDI data source with Tomcat 6 (maybe memory leaks on redeploy).

However, I'm attempting to deploy the same WAR (with the MySql driver) on Tomcat 7 using new connection pooling and getting :
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

I do understand that the more appropriate place for JDBC drivers would be `CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

Does the new connection pooling absolutely requires all JDBC drivers to be in `CATALINA_HOME/lib`? Or some configuration can allow me to ship the driver within WAR.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The driver should be in `CATALINA_HOME\lib` especially if you want to use Tomcat's pooling

From: [Tomcat 7 Connection Pooling](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_%28DBCP%29_Configurations)

> Before you proceed, don't forget to copy the JDBC Driver's jar into
>   $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

Comment: Thank you! While that works, I am still confused why tomcat 6 allows for bundling and tomcat 7 doesn't.